# Distinguish between HTML element and JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, compare

I've realised that both `typeof {}` (JSON object) and `typeof document.getElementById("foo")` (HTML element) equal "object"

In this specific case, I cannot use `.toString()` and compare with, for example, `includes()`.
I haven't been able to find any other alternatives. I thought that maybe checking for undefined innerHTML in the (either JSON or HTML) object would work, but obviously, it won't if the JSON object has a key called that.

How can I distinguish the two? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
function parseJSON(object) {
    if (typeof object !== "object") {
        object = JSON.parse(object);
    }
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        if (typeof value == "object") {
            object[key] = parseJSON(value);
        }
        try {
            var val = eval(value);
            if (val.toString() == ... || typeof val == ...) { //Comparison is here
                val = value;
            }
            console.log(val,value);
        } catch (error) {
            switch (error.constructor) {
                case SyntaxError:
                    continue;
                case ReferenceError:
                    object[key] = value;
                    continue;
                default:
                    console.log(new Error().stack);
                    continue;
            }
        }
        object[key] = val;
    }
    return object;
}
```

EDIT 2 (JSON):

```
{
  "CSS_ATKINSON_FONT": "chrome.runtime.getURL('ttaddons/fonts/Atkinson.css')", //this is supposed to be converted to an URL and it will.
  "REQUESTS": {
    "mazeTheme": "mazeTheme" //this becomes an element through eval()
  },
  "THEMES": [
    {
      "theme": "light",
      "gameTheme": "g_url('assets/images/game/game')" //this function does not exist in the window and the string should remain as is. It's why I have the referenceError check in place
    },
    {
      "theme": "dark",
      "gameTheme": "d_url('ttaddons/game/darkGame')" //neither this
    }
  ],
  "MUSIC": {
    "RussianMarch": "RussianMarch"
  },
  "POPUP": {
    "ELEMENTS": {
      "darkTheme": "#darkTheme" //this is not supposed to become an element, and does not either.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? JSON is a string, not an object.

Comment: I have a kind of redundant but also somewhat necessary setup for parsing a JSON object with eval, JSON.parse. I'll edit in the code for it in my question. The problem pretty much lies in eval selecting HTML objects when I don't want it to. In that case, I attempt to convert it back to a string and that's where my problem arises.

Comment: What sort of argument are you calling `parseJSON` with? I'm not sure I understand the point of this function. Seems like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm fetching a JSON file with an XMLHttpRequest and parsing things that need to get parsed. Also, I have the try/catch statement in place as I have some URL values in the JSON that need to be in order. I can also provide the JSON if that's necessary.

Comment: The more info you add, the stranger this design seems. Are you passing server data that's getting eval'd as JS? This seems dangerous, hard to maintain and unnecessary, but I'm still not sure what problem you're trying to solve in your app so I can't really offer a solution other than to say, there is probably a better way to design this.

Comment: Pretty likely that there is. In my case, security isn't a concern to consider. The fetch is a JSON file in the Chrome extension, an effort to streamline my development process per se. I might do something hacky like checking that some obscure HTML value isn't undefined, but it'd be great to have something to compare and distinguish the two directly.

Regardless, I appreciate the help and you've frankly been a bit more welcoming than what I've seen in my previous posts :)

Comment: All in all I got ~something~ working by making an .ondrop strict comparison to null. I figured it was unlikely that I'm gonna have a key in my JSON called ondrop that coincidentally has a value of null.